# Powershell, how obtain a csv by column with a pscustomobject or ordered?

Tags: string, powershell, csv, filesystemobject, pscustomobject

Being a beginner in Powershell, I have a problem that I can't solve. I get the average of different CSV files as a string with the following code:

```
# recovery of the list of  csv files present in the folder "folder_1".

$files=(Get-ChildItem -path "C:\folder_1\" -Recurse -Include *.csv)
 
#loop to read each file and average the variables "PRESS_CELL" and "PRESS_DELTA
foreach($file in $files){
    $varTemp = @((Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Csv | Measure-Object "PRESS_CELL","PRESS_DELTA" -Average | Export-Csv -Path "C:\folder_1\Alias.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append))
    Write-Host $varTemp
}

#added an increment to sort the data (averages)
$vartemp2 = Import-CSV "C:\folder_1\Alias.csv" | Select *,LINENUMBER | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Line = 1 } { 
$_.LineNumber = $Line++
$_ 
} | Export-CSV "C:\folder_1\Alias2.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host $vartemp2

# sort data by "property" and by "LINENUMBER"

$vartemp3 = Import-Csv "C:\folder_1\Alias2.csv" 
$vartemp3 | % { $_.LINENUMBER = [int]$_.LINENUMBER }
$vartemp3 | Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression = 'Property'; Ascending = $true }, @{ Expression = 'LINENUMBER'; Ascending = $true } |
  Format-Table -Property "Average","Property","LINENUMBER" 

# groups the values obtained in a table/customobject and export it to csv by column ?

$fields = [ordered]@{
PRESS_CELL =  $vartemp3 |  ? property -like *PRESS_CELL* | Select -ExpandProperty Average   
PRESS_DELTA = $vartemp3 | ? property -like *PRESS_DELTA* |Select -ExpandProperty Average 
} 
$fields | export-csv C:\1_ICOS_data\Alias4.csv -Append   ##DOESN'T WORK 
[result][1]
```

However, I would like to export the result as a CSV table (1 column per result with PRESS_CELL and PRESS_DELTA as headers. When I use the pipeline :

```
 | export-csv C:\temp\alias.csv -Append
```

I get a result :

With "ordered"

> "System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection","System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection","False","System.Object","False"

And with pscustomobject :

> System.Object[],"System.Object[]"

Comment: Is it returning an array? You may have to enumerate through it before exporting to get the string out. Try `...Average | Out-String`

Comment: The `Average` is an array of all values found in column `Average`. What would you like to do? Create an average out of all these values, or ??

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. I am sending you attached the complete code. 
The idea is to read all the csv files in a folder and calculate the average for each file per column and aggregate them into a final csv file (each file contains 30 minutes of data at 1 minute time step, and I want to get a final csv file that contains the average for each half hour)

Comment: Thank you for your help !
I obtain this type : 
$fields| Get-Member
   TypeName : System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
or 
$fields |Get-Member
   TypeName : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name           MemberType   Definition                             
----           ----------   ----------                                                     
PRESS_CELL     NoteProperty Object[] PRESS_CELL=System.Object[]    
PRESS_DELTA    NoteProperty Object[] PRESS_DELTA=System.Object[]  
And I think I need to obtain an array of these two variables before export ??

Comment: I would like to have $fields.PRESS_CELL and $fields_PRESS_DELTA per column, in a csv file. But I have the impression that "values" are given in a comma separated string in the powershell result: 

Name                        
PRESS_CELL     Value   {45,6 , 46,7 , 248,9}
And I want in my csv :
PRESS_CELL as header and 45,6, 46,7 et 248,9 per row

Answer (score 0):

Add -NoTypeInformation to export-csv command like that

```
$fields = [ordered]@{
PRESS_CELL = $vartemp3 | ? property -like *PRESS_CELL* | Select -ExpandProperty Average  
PRESS_DELTA = $vartemp3 | ? property -like *PRESS_DELTA* |Select -ExpandProperty Average 
}
#Or:
$fields = [pscustomobject]@{
PRESS_CELL = $vartemp3 | ? property -like *PRESS_CELL* | Select -ExpandProperty Average 
PRESS_DELTA = $vartemp3 | ? property -like *PRESS_DELTA* |Select -ExpandProperty Average }

$fields |export-csv "c:\fields.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I tried with -NoTypeInformation but it doesn't work
Basically i wan't $fields.PRESS_CELL and $fields.PRESS_DELTA by column in a csv, but when i see the result in powershell, the values are all in a string, separated by ","

Comment: The string separated by , is CSV(comma separated value) when open it in excel you will see it as table and you can save it as excel sheet , but if you need cell and delta as column names it is another thing to create a table in power shell I will prepare it and send it

Comment: Hello, 
Yes this is exactly my problem, if I open it in a csv, the values will be separated by commas in columns, however, I would like to get them as rows (with DELTA as the column name, like "transposing" to excel). Thanks in advance!